# Supertabular across pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, supertabular

I am using the `supertabular`environment to split tables over pages.
Does anybody know, how I can give LaTeX a hint, where to break the table and turn to the next page? There are some rows, which should be displayed together.

I Googled around, but could not find an appropriate answer, in Google or the document. `longtable` renders my table unusable. At least as all other tables are displayed with

```
\hline
\hline
```

as the first head and the `longtable` environment seems not to like this sort of tables.
Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27493/how-can-i-break-up-longtables-at-regular-intervals) answers it for `longtable`. without an example of how you are setting up the `longtable` it is not easy to help.

Comment: If use of `longtable` renders a table unusable it must, by definition, be _user error_.