# Vertical alignment of attributes on long table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

I have created a longtable of 4 columns. As shown below. I would like to have the attribute on the first column, in this case "Business" vertical (sideways)instead of horizontal. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c |c | c|}


\hline
\rowcolor{orange}
\textbf{Category} & \textbf{Name} & Yes & No\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long:hey}}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{orange}
\textbf{Category} & \textbf{Name} & Yes & No\\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

  \multirow{7}{*}{\textbf{Business}} & IreneVillas & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \cline{2-4}
    & PhotoCorfu & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \cline{2-4}
    & TradesManager & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \cline{2-4}
    & CWE & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Akron & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \cline{2-4}    
    & TVRepair & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Smart Scan  & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \cline{2-4}

  \hline

   \caption{List of all business websites}\\  
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MikeRenfro code added :)

Comment: It isn't quite compilable or minimal (`\checkmark` probably irrelevant, for example), but adding the `graphicx` package and using `\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Business}}` should work.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with the rotated labels via graphicx, some formatting cleanup from [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), and [ensuring the longtable never breaks up a category](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27512/3345):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{cccc}

\toprule
\textbf{Category} & \textbf{Name} & Yes & No\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}{Continuation of Table \ref{long:hey}}\\
\midrule
\textbf{Category} & \textbf{Name} & Yes & No\\
\midrule
\endhead

\caption{\label{long:hey} List of all business websites}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

  \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Business}}} & IreneVillas & x & x \\*
    & PhotoCorfu & x & x \\*
    & TradesManager & x & x \\*
    & CWE & x & x \\*
    & Akron & x & x \\*
    & TVRepair & x & x \\*
    & Smart Scan  & x & x \\*

  \midrule

  \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Business}}} & IreneVillas & x & x \\*
    & PhotoCorfu & x & x \\*
    & TradesManager & x & x \\*
    & CWE & x & x \\*
    & Akron & x & x \\*
    & TVRepair & x & x \\*
    & Smart Scan  & x & x \\*

  \midrule

  \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Business}}} & IreneVillas & x & x \\*
    & PhotoCorfu & x & x \\*
    & TradesManager & x & x \\*
    & CWE & x & x \\*
    & Akron & x & x \\*
    & TVRepair & x & x \\*
    & Smart Scan  & x & x \\*

  \midrule

  \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Business}}} & IreneVillas & x & x \\*
    & PhotoCorfu & x & x \\*
    & TradesManager & x & x \\*
    & CWE & x & x \\*
    & Akron & x & x \\*
    & TVRepair & x & x \\*
    & Smart Scan  & x & x \\*

  \midrule

  \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Business}}} & IreneVillas & x & x \\*
    & PhotoCorfu & x & x \\*
    & TradesManager & x & x \\*
    & CWE & x & x \\*
    & Akron & x & x \\*
    & TVRepair & x & x \\*
    & Smart Scan  & x & x \\*

  \midrule

  \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Business}}} & IreneVillas & x & x \\*
    & PhotoCorfu & x & x \\*
    & TradesManager & x & x \\*
    & CWE & x & x \\*
    & Akron & x & x \\*
    & TVRepair & x & x \\*
    & Smart Scan  & x & x \\*

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```