# babel ngerman interfering with longtable pagebreaks

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, babel

I have a longtable environment and want pagebreaks only after certain rows which can be achieved putting `*` at the end of the rows that must not be broken (see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27493/how-can-i-break-up-longtables-at-regular-intervals)).

This does work as long as the babel package option is not set to ngerman (or german). Somehow ngerman option seems to prevent the asterisks from working as intended. Setting option `english` does not influence the behavior of `*`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % page breaking does not work
% \usepackage[english]{babel} %  page breaking does work
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\small
\begin{longtable}{p{6cm}lp{6cm}}
\caption{longtable page breaks} \\
\toprule
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\footnotesize Continued on next page... / Fortsetzung nächste Seite}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

\lipsum[66] & 1 & \lipsum[75] \\ * 
shorter text & 2 & shorter text \\ * 
shorter text & 3 & shorter text \\ * 
shorter text & 4 & shorter text \\ * 
shorter text & 5 & shorter text \\ % page break allowed
\lipsum[6] & 6 & \lipsum[6] \\ * 
shorter text & 7 & shorter text \\ * 
shorter text & 8 & shorter text \\ * 
shorter text & 9 & shorter text \\ * 
shorter text & 10 & shorter text \\ % page break allowed
\lipsum[75] & 6 & \lipsum[66] \\ *
shorter text & 12 & shorter text \\ *  
shorter text & 13 & shorter text \\ *
shorter text & 14 & shorter text \\ *
shorter text & 15 & shorter text \\ % page break allowed
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know a solution how to use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` **and** have the page breaks after the intended rows?

Comment: I don't see any problem when I run your example, it all fits on to one page, so no page breaking happens so whether or not page breaking is allowed after `\\ ` does  not play a part?

Comment: If you want to force a page break then as in normal text `\\\pagebreak`

Comment: I get a page break if I add a few lines. The english \lipsum text produce more lines in your example and so breaks earlier.

Comment: Ulrike, you are right. My example is thus lapsed. I have the problem in a larger file but I could not reproduce the error now. Davids proposal `\pagebreak` did help though. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @jmjr With `\documentclass[a5paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}`, I get pagebreaks after lines 5 and 10, both with English and German …